# display featured images of posts with their specific category

Tags: wordpress

```
<?php 
                        $args = array(
                        'show_option_all'    => '',
                        'orderby'            => 'name',
                        'order'              => 'ASC',
                        'style'              => 'list',
                        'show_count'         => 0,
                        'hide_empty'         => 1,
                        'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
                        'child_of'           => 0,
                        'feed'               => '',
                        'feed_type'          => '',
                        'feed_image'         => '',
                        'exclude'            => '',
                        'exclude_tree'       => '',
                        'include'            => '',
                        'hierarchical'       => 1,
                        'title_li'           => __( 'Categories' ),
                        'show_option_none'   => __( '' ),
                        'number'             => null,
                        'echo'               => 1,
                        'depth'              => 0,
                        'current_category'   => 0,
                        'pad_counts'         => 0,
                        'taxonomy'           => 'category',
                        'walker'             => null
                        );
                        wp_list_categories( $args ); 
                    ?>
```

above is my code which display all categories now each category has some posts which have featured images so how to show that featured images on click of specific category.

Comment: please  answer me fast my work has totally stopped due to this issue

Comment: wp_list_categories as a feature does exactly what it was intended to do. It lists categories. Now if you click on a category you would get another view, i guess its the archive view of the category. I would advise you to study the wordpress template structure once again so you know what template you need to change in order to display the images as it has nothing to do with your actual posted snippet.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy